# "Had you not seen her before,you .... her"(not recognize)

Tags: conditional-constructions

> "Had you not seen her before,you .... her"(not recognize)

MyApproach:

I am confused whether to say "would not have recognized" or would have not recognized".

Which to use and Why and if there is any constraints,please Explain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct grammar would be:

Had you not seen her before, you wouldn't have recognised her.

"would have not" is gramatically incorrect and doesn't make sense.